# ¿Como abrir un enlace externo a React Router Dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

estoy haciendo un proyecto personal y quiero que al clickear una imagen me redirija a Facebook pero al clickear me redirige a otra pestaña en el mismo localhoost.
(http://localhost:3000/www.facebook.com)

Busque en internet algo relacionado y no encontré nada, gracias de antemao :D

```html
<a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <img src={facebook} alt="facebook" width="50px" height="50px" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer referencia a un sitio distinto al tuyo tienes que poner el link incluyendo el protocolo:

prueba:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <img src={facebook} alt="facebook" width="50px" height="50px" />
</a>
```

Comment: Listo hermano, muchas gracias

Comment: @AlexisBermúdez considera votar y aceptar la respuesta si fue de ayuda, saludos