# Pasar props de un componente hijo a un componente padre en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

si alguien me puediera ayudar, el problema es que tengo un componente padre que recibe un arreglo de comida ej=[comida1, comida2, comdia3] y por cada elemento del arreglo estoy generando un componente.
En cada componente hijo estoy generando un precio y quiero sumar todos los precios de cada arreglo hijo, estoy usando un useState en el componente padre para pasar las props de los hijos al padre y un useEffect en el padre para que cada que haya cambio en el state del padre se actualice pero solo me toma el precio del ultimo arreglo y no se porque hace eso...
Pd: La imagen es del componente padre.
de antemano gracias por la ayuda :3[image: componente padre]

Comment: El código tiene un problema de referencias, para poder ayudarte por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código con formato de texto [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). También recuerda que debes [aceptar y votar las preguntas que has hecho en la comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/480170/como-abrir-un-enlace-externo-a-react-router-dom) sobre todo si te fueron de ayuda. Hay que recordar que estas acciones mantienen el sitio bien documentado. Saludos

Comment: como que problemas de referencia?
editar la pregunta de que manera?

Comment: Edita la pregunta agregando el código mínimo utilizable para reproducir el problema, con foto no va, coloca el código como tal., como ya te dijeron puede ser problema de referencias pero sin ver tu código es una especulación.

Comment: como te indican, escribe tu codigo aqui para poder revisarlo, lo que yo te puedo especular es que cada vez que agregas cosas al tu contexto se esta sustituyendo el objeto que ya existe, para resolverlo puedes hacer una copia del objeto para que no se sobre escriba

Comment: Pude resolverlo, lo que pasa es que estaba usando el contexto en cada hijo para obtener la funcion que almacenaba los precios, entonces cada componente cambiaba el valor en lugar de almacenarlos